# NGINX match multiple paths with proxy pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to pass multiple locations to a proxy, though, I can simply not make it work. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

This is what I have so far:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404
            gzip on;
    }

    location ~* ^/(login|callback|ph|ch|th) {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4002;
    }
```

As you probably can tell, I'm trying to pass

- /login
- /callback
- /ph
- /ch
- /th

to localhost on port 4002, but it's not passing them?

**EDIT:** If it's of any help. I think my front-end it hijacking the path-location? Not sure though.

Answer (score 6):

All requests are starts from /, so your location should look like this:

```
location ~* ^/(login|callback|ph|ch|th) {
```

if you use start string symbol.

Comment: Whoops, it was from a test I made. Fixed it in the question, sorry!

Comment: If you have the same problem after fix, then you have the problem with you app I think. Show us whole nginx config please.